# Warnings in Movable Type 5.2.3 with PSGI/Plack

Tags: movabletype, plack

I am running MT-5.2.3 under PSGI/Plack behind a Apache reverse proxy. The server is Starman. The Plack logs show a warning for each call:

> WARNING: Automatically converting Plack::App::Directory instance to a
>   PSGI code reference. If you see this warning for each request, you
>   probably need to explicitly call to_app() i.e.
>   Plack::App::Directory->new(...)->to_app in your PSGI file.

What should I do to fix this? AFAICS, the stock mt.psgi already calls `MT::PSGI->to_app()`.

Thank you.

Comment: PSGI/Plack support within Movable Type is a very new feature.  For any warning like this, I would file a case at http://movabletype.fogbugz.com/.  I filed a case for this already, [Warning Reported by Customer When Running MT Under PSGI/Plack on Starman](https://movabletype.fogbugz.com/default.asp?109552)

Comment: Thank you for submitting this. Will add to it if I find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Six Apart [reports that this problem was fixed](https://movabletype.fogbugz.com/default.asp?109552) in a [recent commit to the Movable Type project](https://github.com/movabletype/movabletype/commit/732c3fed7e7e939709050bdddfb1c66802f4c1a8) that will be part of a future release of Movable Type.

I generally don't recommend running unreleased versions of Movable Type for production purposes, but I think it would be OK to patch MT::PSGI to get rid of these warnings.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I appreciate SA's prompt response.

Comment: Six Apart seems to have fixed this and informed me. Thanks to Dave and SA for great support